# Mac OS X problem starting FTP from preferences

Tags: macos, ftp, launchctl

When I try to enable the FTP service in the preferences (File Sharing->Options->Share Files and Folders Using FTP) the check box enables and then disables again.  The console is giving me the message :

```
16/04/2010 12:14:20 com.apple.coreservicesd[51] sh: launchctl: command not found
```

This indicates to me that it can't find the launchctl executable

launchctl is present in the folder /bin

/bin is set in the PATH variable for sh and bash shells and also in the ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist

How can I fix this so that my preferences can find this so that I can enable the FTP service.

I have since removed my environment.plist file, and this has made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `/bin/launchctl` you should get a prompt saying `launchd%`. If you don't it's quite likely your installed copy of `launchctl` is corrupted - if this is the case you can try an "Archive and Install" to re-install Mac OS X without touching your user folder.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check

```
file /System/Library/CoreServices/coreservicesd
```

that is the actual command run from *com.apple.coreservicesd* plist.